# How long would it take for a For loop to run through 1000 loops?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a SELECT query that could return a 1000 names max - more likely to return 300-400 names.

I would like to compare an input string to the names in the array returned by the SELECT query.

I have two questions:

1. How long would a for loop take to run through (all the 1000 names in ) the array to find if there is a matching value? AND
2. Is there a way to terminate the loop as soon as a match is found? (Suppose a match is found on the 10th name, running through the rest would be a waste. It doesn't matter if there are more matches - just hitting the first one is enough for my purpose.)

I have tried return, and exit but both don't work exactly the way I'd like.

Here are the codes I am running to test the idea:
The first php file contains the array of names

```
<?php 
$names=array("R","A","V");
$arrlengths=count($names);
?>
```

and is included in the second file.

```
<?php
include 'test-2nd-include.php';
//the above file contains an array with three names
//it also contains the length of the array in the arrlengths variable


//in the test case we are using a name assigned to a variable in this file
//however, when used on the registration page, it will be a value that has come through   $_POST

$rr = "A";

 //a test variable that is initially = 0 but will be incremented if value is found in array

$ohno = 0;


for($xx=0;$xx<$arrlengths;$xx++)
{
echo "$ names [ $xx ] ", $names[$xx]; 
echo "<br>";


   if ($names[$xx] ==$rr) {
           // if the value is found then the test variable is set t
            $ohno = 1;
    }
}
if ($ohno > 0){
    echo " $rr already exists in our members list" ;
}
else {
echo "Congratulations! $rr is still available!" ;
}

?>
```

What I have seen is that if I use return or exit after `$ohno = 1;` the messages at the end do not get processed. If I move the `if ($ohno > 0){......$rr is still available!" ;}` into the for loop the results are really weird!

I am sure I am missing something but after staring at this for an entire afternoon, I still cannot find a way to make the code stop running after it encounters the first match AND display the appropriate messages - both when it finds a match and when it doesn't.

And that is the reason for the first question! Is the time I am spending trying to do this worth the saving in terms of server time/processing in the long run? After all, with a max of 1000 expected users, this code might run about 300-400 times over a period of a month or so?!?

Comment: break; will leave your loop. Try to add it in your if.

Comment: I totally agree with @YourCommonSense... This question would never have existed if you had used the `WHERE` SQL clause.

Comment: @Brewal you cant say that for sure :)

Comment: Yes I can, there would have only one single SQL query (about 0.01 ms) and no loop... Nothing to worry about "time"

Comment: @Brewal Hes echoing every name until the match is found a where clause is not the answer

Comment: This have to be for debugging purpose. Nobody wants to see `$ names [ n ] name` a thousand time. Anyway, let's the auhtor talk about it.

Comment: @Brewal "has to be" could be a over statement :) i agree...I understand `where` your coming from( I hope you get that joke) but I tend to take the author more literally

Comment: @Brewal - Yes this is for debugging purpose only - just to see what happens at each step of the code..... There are actually two reasons I am having to take this route (1). My host doesn't allow AJAX - if they did, I could just have sent a query to check for existing names and been done with it. (2) without the AJAX, the only way that I can do the comparison without having to reload the page on failure (and making my users run away) is to pull the names into the page before-hand and run a quick check on the array before a user types in all the other details. That is why I have not used WHERE!

Comment: @tman Well, that's nice to have both of the speeches. I'm not trying to say you are wrong, I couldn't just ommit notice this.

Comment: @vinaya see my answer then :) ...Im not sure why exactly you cant change your query to put the work on the database but to each its on -

Comment: Your host doesn't allow Ajax? How can they block it? from the server's point of view all http requests are equal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

whats wrong with
 `if ($names[$xx] ==$rr) {
            echo " $rr already exists in our members list" ;
            $ohno = 1;break;` then out side the loop an if `if ($ohno == 0){
    echo "Congratulations! $rr is still available!" ;
}`

The length of time really depends on several factors and I don't feel is a straight forward answer.

Comment: This is not the root of the problem. Retrieving all the database to see if a username already exists is the main issue here. That's a severe performance issue !

Comment: @Brewal i think your inferring things the author didn't specifically state

Comment: @tman - thanks! So simple really! I moved the `already exists` message to just before setting `$ohno = 1` , a `break` to just after and the `$ohno ==0` by itself in an `if` at the end. The echos of the names in the loop clearly show how many times the loop had run and at what point it stopped running! EXACTLY the way I wanted it!

Answer (score 3):

To end a loop early use the `break;` statement.

But, as you're obviously trying to check whether or not a name already exists in a SQL table you probably should rather directly ask the database for the information:

`select true from YourUserTable where name = 'theName' limit 1`

Then check whether 1 or 0 rows are returned. If one row is returned the name already exists; if the result set is empty the name is still available. This is much faster than first getting the whole user name list from the database and then manually check it.

If you still want to iterate:

```
$found = false;
// Of course, a for loop is also possible
foreach ($namesArray as $position => $name) { 
    if ($name == $nameYouAreLookingFor) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($found)
    echo "The name already exists";
else 
    echo "The name is still available";
```